# Cannot use fontface for custom fonts

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to use custom fonts 
But its not showing on my website.

```css
/*TEXT*/
p.fontcheck {
    font-family: MTCORSVA bold;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


/*fonts*/
@font-face {
font-family: "MTCORSVA";
src: url("/eccube_1/html/template/default/css/fonts/MTCORSVA.TTF") format("TTF");
}
```

```html
<p class="fontcheck">HELLO TEST</p>
```

I tried `URL` in whole path too, or by inserting `HTTP or HTTPS` too. 
Results isnt appearing. 
My original path to fonts in server is

```
/public_html/azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/css/fonts/MTCORSVA.TTF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this works!

```css
/*TEXT*/
p.fontcheck {
    font-family: MTCORSVA bold;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


/*fonts*/
@font-face {
font-family: MTCORSVA;
src: url(http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/css/fonts/MTCORSVA.TTF);
}
```

```html
<p class="fontcheck">HELLO TEST</p>
```

Comment: Tried didnt work. Here is the link to the [site](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/fontcheck)